# How to make a column describing order of elements?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to add a column to a table that describes the order of the rows by other value. For example, i have the following data:

```
popularity = 1, id =1
popularity = 1, id =2
popularity = 2, id =3
popularity = 3, id =4
popularity = null, id=5
```

I want a query to get the following:

```
popularity = 1, id =1, newOrder = 4
popularity = 1, id =2, newOrder = 3
popularity = 2, id =3, newOrder = 2
popularity = 3, id =4, newOrder = 1
popularity = null, id=5, newOrder = 5
```

The rules that apply here is:
- On same popularity, order by id
- The highest popularity is the first on the new order
- The null popularity is the lowest on the new order

Im trying to do this because the table has millions of rows, and doing a pagination by popularity and using offset is really slow. So having this new order will allow me to do something like id > page*page_amount.

It would be great to have an update query that sets this value because the select query with offset is really slow.

Thanks

Comment: *"Im trying to do this because the table has millions of rows, and doing a pagination by popularity and using offset is really slow"* Is there application code involved?  in general you should be fine performancewise when you use the "left off" approach more or less like `SELECT .... WHERE id >= 100000 LIMIT 100 ORDER BY id` instead of  `SELECT ... LIMIT 100000, 100`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this if anyone needs the same:

```
SET @actual_id := 0;
UPDATE file 
SET main_listing_page = (@actual_id:=@actual_id+1)
WHERE status = 1 And title_date is not null
ORDER BY popularity desc, id desc;
```

It uses a dynamic variable that changes in every step.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ORDER BY popularity desc, id desc`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select . . .,
       row_number() over (order by (popularity is not null) desc, popularity desc, id) as newOrder
from t;
```

Comment: "On same popularity, order by id" is missing here.

Comment: I need to make the update on a new column to set this new order value, the select query has much delay because i need to use offset.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of MySql does not allow window functions:

```
update tablename t
inner join (
  select 
    t.id, 
    (select count(*) from tablename 
     where 
       coalesce(popularity, 0) > coalesce(t.popularity, 0)
       or
       (coalesce(popularity, 0) = coalesce(t.popularity, 0) and id >= t.id)
    ) counter  
  from tablename t
) c on c.id = t.id
set t.neworder = c.counter;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qtRGFycPKbbNkEV8WWwveB/0).
For MySql 8.0+:

```
update tablename t
inner join (
  select 
    t.id, 
    row_number() over (order by coalesce(popularity, 0) desc, id desc) counter  
  from tablename t
) c on c.id = t.id
set t.neworder = c.counter;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qtRGFycPKbbNkEV8WWwveB/1).
Results:

```
| id  | popularity | neworder |
| --- | ---------- | -------- |
| 1   | 1          | 4        |
| 2   | 1          | 3        |
| 3   | 2          | 2        |
| 4   | 3          | 1        |
| 5   |            | 5        |
```